# SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, crash

Today my Windows-10 computer "ran into a problem". I don't remember doing any system critical things before.

[image: Bluescreen image]

The problem is that... there is no real message here! It just says "Hey, your computer crashed because... an error.".

What should I do? And where can I find the safe mode to rescue my PC? I have upgraded from Windows 7 (but that was a month or so ago), a HP computer.

I also already tried unplugging all USB devices - result: nothing changed.

P.S.: Here is my research list (I am not allowed to post more than 2 links :( ): http://txs.io/jXQb

Comment: share the dmp files (OneDrive share link) from C:\Windows\Minidump

Comment: @magicandre1981 OK, wait, I'll start Ubuntu to get them...

Comment: Ubuntu can't mount my disk. :(

Comment: after several failed boots, Windows will show the recovery options. Here you can boot to safe mode. store the files to an external drive and upload the dmps (compressed in 1 Zip) from a 2nd PC.

Comment: OK. Do hardware shutdowns also count? The computer doesn't restart itself.

Comment: (long press on power button)

Comment: here is the Ubuntu message (probably not that relevant but maybe it is...): http://i.imgur.com/ftKW6KY.jpg

Comment: I'm just restarting the 4th time... Strange:http://i.imgur.com/KqO1hkh.jpg

Comment: this happens when you hibernate Windows (or use the new fastStartup since Win8). Try to boot Windows 3 times and now Windows should show the recovery options.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35650/discussion-between-pal-sch-and-magicandre1981).